# Can the Validator ensure a certain Datum is sent by the Redeemer?

Tags: plutus

is it possible for a Validator to ensure that the redeemer pays some Value along with a certain Datum attached to it? Looking at the possible transaction methods on the ScriptContext, checks are only done on the Value and not the Datum. I see the DatumHash types but am not sure what it is used for.[image]

Comment: Hope my answer was helpful. I'm not sure if you're overloading the term "Redeemer" (the redeemer data type vs the sender of that tx). I think I got what you were going for though. LMK if I can clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validator can ensure that a datum or multiple datums are included in the output.

Take the [Uniswap clone](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/cfaa1438d2b391e8294fc3b8317b3768e78aa711/plutus-use-cases/src/Plutus/Contracts/Uniswap/OnChain.hs) in the plutus-use-cases for example:

The `validateCreate` method ensures that an updated `Factory` datum

```
Constraints.checkOwnOutputConstraint ctx (OutputConstraint (Factory $ lp : lps) $ unitValue usCoin)
```

and a new `Pool` datum

```
Constraints.checkOwnOutputConstraint ctx (OutputConstraint (Pool lp liquidity) $ valueOf lpCoinA outA <> valueOf lpCoinB outB <> unitValue c)
```

are included in the outputs.

Both of these are attached to some `Value`.

Comment: Oh gosh I didn't know there was a whole library on On-Chain Constraints. Thank you!

As for the term Redeemer, I believe the language used has been not-strict enough. So to my understanding, the person initiating the transaction is called the Redeemer, and he/she will supply a RedeemerType to the Validator to spend the underlying eUTXO.

Link to the On-Chain constraints library: [https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/160d158c2679a72adfc8edf7a1c43a4b59189d99/plutus-ledger/src/Ledger/Constraints/OnChain.hs]

Comment: Yeah. The on-chain constraints are great and they compliment the off-chain constraints well. The more declarative the better :)